# Unity instantiation not working at all, no errors in code but still not working

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm trying to instantiate a prefab in a loop, but the first time the instantiate function is called, the code breaks out of the function for no reason. I've used the stepping tools in Visual Studio and can't figure out why it's doing this. I thought it might be because of my version of Unity but I've just updated to 2019.3.0f6 and the problem is still occurring. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
public void GotTickets(FBTicket[] tickets)
{
    if (ticketHolders.Count < tickets.Length)
    {
        int amountNeeded = tickets.Length - ticketHolders.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < amountNeeded; i++)
        {
            TicketHolder ticketHolder = Instantiate(ticketHolderPrefab, ticketHolderParent).GetComponent<TicketHolder>();
            ticketHolders.Add(ticketHolder);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ticketHolders.Count; i++)
    {
        ticketHolders[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < tickets.Length; i++)
    {
        ticketHolders[i].SetTicket(tickets[i].jackpot, tickets[i].numbers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the first section of your code could be greatly simplified: `while (ticketHolders.Count < tickets.Length) ticketHolders.Add(Instantiate(etc...))`

Comment: Not sure of which "loop" you are talking about. Before your last `for` loop, can you display with some Debug.Log command what is the values of both `ticketHolders.Count` and  `tickets.Length` ?

Comment: Also note that while ticketHolders may have already have some elements, are you sure none of them are `null`? That would definitely break the first loop after the `if` block

Comment: The last two loops are irrelevant, the code past the point of instantiation isn't ran. But the length of tickets is varied, for testing it has a length of 13, and ticketHolders has a count of 0.

Comment: How do you reference ticketPrefab? Did you make a public property that you set in the inspector? That always gets me is I make the property but forget to drag the prefab into it in the inspector. Also, if you split the instantiation from the GetComponent call, does it make it past the instantiation?

Comment: Yes, it's set in the inspector using a prefab from my project. I've ran it without using the GetComponent call and it still breaks at instantiation.

Comment: Easy set a breakpoint here "  int amountNeeded = tickets.Length - ticketHolders.Count;".......The step through the code line by line inspecting all the variables to see what is going on.

Comment: That's what I have done, amount needed is equal to 13, as the first Instantiate is called the debugging stops, as if it encountered an error, but no errors are shown.

Comment: my guess is that either the prefab or the parent are null.... or most likely amountNeeded is equals to 1 so it only iterates once

Comment: Then set a try { }catch(Exception ex) {}............inside the for loop... and place a break point inside the catch and inspect the exception

Comment: If you break up `TicketHolder ticketHolder = Instantiate(ticketHolderPrefab, ticketHolderParent).GetComponent<TicketHolder>();` into two lines -- the first line for the `Instantiate`, the second for the `GetComponent` -- then where exactly does it exit the loop?

Comment: I've just tried catching the exception and it says the exception is null :/

Comment: Also I've already tried splitting up instantiation and GetComponent. But it doesn't break out of the loop, it breaks out of the whole function as Instantiate is called

Comment: This is weird man. The only other thing I can think is ticketHolderParent is null/wasnt set in the inspector. Ive used the Instantiate method recently in my project in basically the exact same way you are, even inside a loop, and I never had the issue you are having. :/

Comment: I don't know whether this will make a difference or not, but this function is being called from another script as a delegate. I request the tickets from the database, passing the name of the function as a delegate, and once its receives them calls the function above.

Comment: *I've just tried catching the exception and it says the exception is null * You've made a mistake. Exceptions aren't null. Maybe you need to go one step further in the step debugger to get the variable populated, or something of that kind.

Comment: It literally says the Exception is null, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I've found a work around for this. Originally the function was being called from another script once the data had been received. To overcome the problem I saved the data to a variable and set a bool to true (like a flag), the next frame the bool would be checked and execute the function. It's not ideal and not the most robust method but at least it works!

Answer (score 0):

Are all your first chance exceptions enabled? In VS 2019 go to Debug > Windows > Exception Settings.  Check all Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Try again and you might get a helpful exception.

[image: CLR exceptions]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've just tried this and I'm afraid it's still not working.